# Marriage Problem: Is both sided stable matching strongly pareto optimal?

Tags: game-theory

According to this problem: [Unique Stable Solution in Stable Marriage Problem: Is it Pareto-efficient and a Nash Equilibrium?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/88215/unique-stable-solution-in-stable-marriage-problem-is-it-pareto-efficient-and-a)

Is the both sided stable matching strongly pareto optimal for both sides? And is there a rule that in a m- and w-optimal stable matching at least one person gets his first choice like in the example?